# GitHub push commit by mistake

Tags: git, github

I add 8 commit to branch on github and then create new branch and add 6 new commit to it and when i update the project i commit the changes to the first branch by mistake how can i revert this commit and return to the previous version before commit
this message appear on the first branch that i commit by mistake on it

This branch is 6 commits behind solutionRestructure.

what i can do now to get the previous version ??

https://github.com/FatenElhariry/Gigs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to keep your commit history, use `git revert ...` and then push to the remote repository. This will make a new commit that just a reverse of the commits you specified.

If you need to delete the commit history completely, use `git reset --hard ...` and force push (`git push -f`) to the remote repository. It'll move `HEAD` backward and also reset `working directory`. Use both `reset --hard` and `push -f` commands with caution as it might result in data loss.

It seems that you want to study more about Git. Take a look at.
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes